# GWT: Draggable Popup with Scrollpanel

Tags: java, gwt

Designed a popup which is draggable, works as designed. Now `Popup` panel contains the `ScrollPanel` it is having vertical scroll bars, but while trying to scroll with dragging is not working

Comment: Provide us a code snippet or any error info you are getting

Comment: i am not getting any error, i am trying to scroll and see the content in scrollpanel, but it is not allowing instead it dragging popup the way i dragged scroll snubber

Comment: Provide us the code snippet

Comment: On Mouse event implementation:
public void onMouseDown(MouseDownEventevent){
beginDragging(event);
}
public void onMouseMove(MouseMoveEventevent){
continueDragging(event);
}
public void onMouseUp(MouseUpEventevent){
endDragging();
}

Comment: Implementation for Dragging:
private void beginDragging(MouseDownEventevent){
dragging=true;
DOM.setCapture(this.getElement());
dragStartX=event.getX();
dragStartY=event.getY();
}
private void continueDragging(MouseMoveEventevent){
if(dragging){
int absX=event.getX()+getAbsoluteLeft();
if(absX<clientLeft||absX>=windowWidth||(event.getY()+getAbsoluteTop())<clientTop){
return;
}
setPopupPosition(absX-dragStartX,absY-dragStartY);
}
}
private void endDragging(){
dragging=false;
DOM.releaseCapture(this.getElement());
}

Comment: Above 2 comments are my logic for dragging: first comment mouseDown initiate drag, mousemove startdragging and mouseup stopped dragging Second comment : beginDragging() -- initiate drag, continuedraging() -- started dragging, endDragging() -- stoped dragging

Answer (score 0):

The following link gives u a window box implementation which is draggable. You can add scroll panel to it. I have tried it. It works. Have a look at it.

http://svn.clazzes.org/svn/gwt/branches/gwt-extras-0.1-branch/src/main/java/org/clazzes/gwt/extras/dialog/WindowBox.java

Comment: This doesn't worked for me:
WindowBox db = new WindowBox();
  HTML w = new HTML("Test Dragging me<br/>Charan<br/>Kumar<br/>Sarvepalli");
  w.setStyleName("test");
  ScrollPanel sp = new ScrollPanel(w);
  sp.setSize("85px", "65px");
  db.setWidget(sp);
  db.center();
This is how i used let me know any issue

Comment: WindowBox Extending DialogBox, GWT DialogBox never allow to fire the mouse events on content widget, it only allows on Caption Widget only. So it doesn't work. This reason behind instead of extending dialogbox i extended popup panel in my designed class